# ¿Como recibo una imagen, desde otra aplicación mediante la opción compartir con.?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview, sharedpreferences

[image: Proceso para recibir la imagen desde otra aplicación]
Tengo desarrollado una aplicación en Android versión 29, el cual contiene un *GridView* dentro de un *ConstraintLayout*. ¿Cómo hago para que este GridView se cargue o reciba imágenes desde otra aplicación, mediante la opción (**compartir con:**) de Android?.
Por ejemplo: Estoy usando el WhatsApp, me llegan fotos, a estas fotos quisiera trasladarlos directamente a mi aplicación desde la opción (**compartir con:**), al usar esta opción, mi aplicación tendrá que estar presente en la lista de aplicaciones a compartir.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#3F4245">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvw_imagenes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#343638"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_enviar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_buscarimg" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_enviar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303234"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="2"
    android:shadowDy="2"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:text="@string/enviar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

La imágen estará presentes en el GridView antes de ser enviadas a un servidor.

Answer (score -1):

Para que tu app esté disponible en Android Sharesheet y poder recibir imágenes desde otras aplicaciones, lo primero que debes hacer es decírselo a tu app a través del Manifest con el siguiente intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityToLoadImage" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```